# how to tokenize and search with special characters in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, special-characters, tokenize

I need texts like *#tag1 quick brown fox #tag2* to be tokenized into `#tag1`, `quick`, `brown`, `fox`, `#tag2`, so I can search this text on any of the patterns `#tag1`, `quick`, `brown`, `fox`, `#tag2` where the symbol `#` must be included in the search term. In my index mapping I have a `text` type field (to search on `quick`, `brown`, `fox`) with the `keyword` type subfield (to search on `#tag`), and when I use search term `#tag` it gives me only the match on the first token `#tag1` but not on `#tag1`.
I think what I need is a tokenizer that will produce word boundary tokens that inlcude special chars. Can someone suggest a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to include `#` in your search, you should use different analyzer than `standard analyzer` because `#` will be removed during analyze phase. You can use `whitespace analyzer` to analyze your text field.
Also for search you can use wildcard pattern:

**Query:**

```
GET [Your index name]/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "[FieldName]": "#tag*"
    }
  }
}
```

You can find information about Elastic built-in analyzer [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-analyzers.html).

**UPDATE:**

Whitespace analyzer:

```
POST /_analyze
{
  "analyzer": "whitespace",
  "text": "#tag1 quick #tag2"
}
```

**Result:**

```
{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "#tag1",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 5,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "quick",
      "start_offset" : 6,
      "end_offset" : 11,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 1
    },
    {
      "token" : "#tag2",
      "start_offset" : 12,
      "end_offset" : 17,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 2
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see #tag1 and #tag2 are two tokens.

Comment: whitespace analyzer uses whitespace tokenizer that strips special chars from the beginning of the words that it tokenizes. Hence the query `"[FieldName]": "#tag*"` won't produce a match.

Comment: Whitespace doesn't remove special characters you can check official documentation here. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-whitespace-analyzer.html

Comment: Interesting, with the query that @Kaveh suggested, the search finds appropriate matches even though my (not whitespace) tokenizer strips # from tokens. But I use `simple_query_string` to take advantage of search operators and it doesn't get matches: GET /myindex/_search {"query": {"simple_query_string": {"query":"#tag*", "fields":["content"]}}} 
Can you suggest how to fix the query?

Comment: Could you please accept and upvote my answer thanks.

Comment: I accepted your answer but it doesn't allow me to upvote

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Kaveh suggestion, I found my mistake. My custom analyzer (with lots of filters, etc) was using standard tokenizer which I thought is similar to whitespace tokenizer. Once I switched to whitespace tokenizer in my custom analyzer I can see that the analyzer doesn't strip `#` from the beginning of the words anymore, and I can search on patterns started with `#` using `simple_query_string` query type.